# switch modes while maintaining file lock

Tags: c, file

I am writing a c program where I need to switch file mode from write to append but also need to maintain the file lock that I applied to the file by opening it in write mode. How do I maintain the file lock state and switch to append mode where user can enter text to it.

I am using c language to code and fcntl to lock the file. and using fopen() to open the files. Can I open multiple instances of the same file using different pointers?

I opened the file for first time in write mode at the start of the code, then, when I approach the append option in my program, I made another pointer and opened the same file using fopen() in append mode, without closing the first file. I know this is wrong approach, but I fear if I close the first file Pointer using fclose() before opening it in append mode, the file lock that I implemented in it will be released which I don't want to. Can anyone tell me the correct approach for this?

My functionality is basically this:

> Open a file

> Apply advisory file locking to it

> Let user edit that file (add text to it or delete the file or print its contents )

> Warm the user for simultaneous edit(if any) but then allow them to continue

Code snippets:

```
//to open file in write mode at the very beginning of program
FILE *fd = fopen(argv[1], "w");
int result = flock(fileno(fd), LOCK_SH);

//set fcntl
static struct flock lock;
lock.l_type = F_WRLCK;
lock.l_start = 0;
lock.l_whence = SEEK_SET;
lock.l_len = 0;
lock.l_pid = getpid();
int ret = fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &lock);

//switch case to append data
FILE *fPtr = fopen(argv[1], "a");
        printf("Enter contents to store in file : \n");
        gets(data);
        fprintf(fPtr, "%s", data);
        printf("Data added to the file successfully");
        fclose(fPtr);
        break;

//switch case to print contents:
fPtr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        while(fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, fPtr) != NULL)
    {
     totalRead = strlen(buffer);
     buffer[totalRead - 1] = buffer[totalRead - 1] == '\n'
                                ? '\0'
                                : buffer[totalRead - 1];
     printf("%s\n", buffer);
     }fclose(fPtr);
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to switch modes like this. Why do you think you need to do this? Why can't you open it in the desired mode in the first place?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Also, please show the actual code rather than trying to describe it in words.

Comment: The first paragraph says you want to change from write mode to append mode, but the last paragraph says you're changing from read to append. Which is it really?

Comment: I implemented file locking by opening it in write mode, then after locking the file, I need to append some data to it so need to switch mode.

Comment: If you're locking the file, and all the writers follow the locking protocol, what difference does it make whether it's write or append? Just seek to the end of the file and write.

Comment: Sorry it was write to append. Im going to edit my question right away.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the code. Please have a look @kaylum